# Two button pressed at the same time

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two buttons left and right, and I just want when both are pressed together then both logs will be showing.

```
 val handleTouch = View.OnTouchListener { v, event ->

        val leftDown : Int
        when(v){
            btn_leftThumb -> when (event.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> pressed(true, null)
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> pressed(false, null)
            }

            btn_rightThumb -> when (event.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> pressed(null, true)
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> pressed(null, false)
            }

        }

        true
    }

    btn_leftThumb.setOnTouchListener(handleTouch)
    btn_rightThumb.setOnTouchListener(handleTouch)


private fun pressed(left:Boolean?, right:Boolean?){

    if(left == true && right == true){
        Log.i(TAG, "BOTH")
    }else if(left == false && right == true){
        Log.i(TAG, "RIGHT")
    }else if(left == true && right == false){
        Log.i(TAG, "LEFT")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution:

private var actionLeft: String = ""

private var actionRight: String = ""

and onCreate:

val handleTouch = View.OnTouchListener { v, event ->

```
        when(v){
            btn_leftThumb -> when (event.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {actionLeft = "DOWN"
                    pressed(actionLeft, actionRight)
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {actionLeft = "UP"
                    pressed(actionLeft, actionRight)
                }
            }

            btn_rightThumb -> when (event.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {actionRight = "DOWN"
                    pressed(actionLeft, actionRight)
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {actionRight = "UP"
                    pressed(actionLeft, actionRight)

                }
            }


        }

        true
    }



    btn_leftThumb.setOnTouchListener(handleTouch)
    btn_rightThumb.setOnTouchListener(handleTouch)
```

private fun pressed(left:String?, right:String?){

```
    if(right == "DOWN" && left =="DOWN") {
        Log.d(TAG, "DOWN")
    }else if (right == "UP" && left =="DOWN"){
        Log.d(TAG, "CANCELLED")
    }else if (right == "DOWN" && left =="UP"){
        Log.d(TAG, "CANCELLED")
    }else if (right == "UP" && left =="UP"){
        Log.d(TAG, "CANCELLED")
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to store the pressed state for each button in some global variable and in onTouchListener update and then check both variables using your method `pressed()`